# How can I tell a DefaultDataTable to refresh itself?

Tags: wicket

I am new to Wicket. I have a search page with two fields, `startDate` and `endDate`, inside a form that is inside a panel. The panel contains a `DefaultDataTable`. When the user submits the form, I use the `startDate` and `endDate` in the `onSubmit()` to get the results. However, my table remains empty. How do I tell the `DefaultDataTable` to refresh?

I have added a form and a submit button to [this example](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/simple-sortable-datatable-example.html). If I want to change the contents of the list, where do I do it?

```
 Button submitButton = new Button("submitButton"){
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(){
            System.out.println("submit button was clicked");
        }
    };

    Form myForm = new Form("myForm");
    myForm.add(submitButton);
    add(myForm);
```

Comment: can you show the relevant snippets of html and java code?

Comment: I have added more info to it. My actual code uses a custom component and there is lot of other things in the component which makes it difficult to paste here. but it is sort of the same as the example listed above

Comment: Does the your DataProvider.iterator() returns a iterator depending on the 2 Dates in the page?

Comment: Thank you so much, I kept changing the wrong list. I updated the list of the data provider using setData() and that worked. I didn't think of looking there until I saw your comment. If you could reply as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my comment as proper answer: make the DataProvider.iterator() dependend on the 2 Dates.